# Access 2010 linked table check

Tags: sql, ms-access, connection, ms-access-2010

I am stumped.  I have a database with two back ends. One is local on a network and the other is over the Internet.  When my database is started the user must pass through a logon and once this happens the main form is opened.  At this time a query is run to send data from local back end to the external one over the Internet via a linked table. What I am looking to do is check if the linked table has a connection and only run this query if the linked table is connected. The reason for this is that if either the end user or the server the database connects to over the Internet don't have an Internet connection at the time it locks up the users front end.  This is no good as this will limit users from using the database if the Internet connection is lost or the server goes down for any such reason

```
Example: if sql link is ok then
         run query
         Else goto end
```

Comment: the tables Name is "ACTIVE" <---- this needs to be checked to make sure there is a link

Comment: Is this even possible or am i barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711216%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to get a suitable folder on the network, if it fails, you do not have a connection.

EDIT

[This article](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/find-sql-server-port) uses VBScript to check for SQL Server ports. VBScript runs in VBA with very few changes.

EDIT #2

Powershell can be used to ping remote servers and [can be run from VBA](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1585510)

```
$servers = Get-Content 'servers.txt'
ForEach-Object ($server in $servers) {
   # Ping the machine to see if it's on the network
   $results = Get-WMIObject -query "select StatusCode from
Win32_PingStatus where Address = '$server'"
   $responds = $false  
   ForEach-Object ($result in $results) {
      # If the machine responds break out of the result loop and indicate success
      if ($result.statuscode -eq 0) {
         $responds = $true
         break
      }
   }
         If ($responds) {
      # Gather info from the server because it responds
      Write-Output "$server responds"
   } else {
      # Let the user know we couldn't connect to the server
      Write-Output "$server does not respond"
   }
}
```

**The code above is a cut-and-paste from: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/let-powershell-do-an-inventory-of-your-servers/ by Allen White**

Comment: thanks will look into this is, will this work over the internet to a server that only port 1433 and 1434 are open for sql only rest are locked down

Comment: thank you very much that has givin me the basics but it seems to report if the local network sql is active and in most cases the local sql will still be actibe but not the external sql over the net using this cod could i specify an IP aswell?

Comment: thanks heaps for the help so far. i had i play around with the power shell clip i showed me but i am getting unexpected token error in two places. Also i am wondering how i am going to get the query to start if this external operation "passes the test". is there a derivitive of this for vba. note this is my forst encounter with powershell

Comment: ok this is what i have come up with from snippets ive found around the place will place credit when find out all the writers,

Comment: Private Sub Detail_Click()
Dim strComputer As String
 strComputer = "ip Adress here"
 If Not SystemOnline(strComputer) Then
MsgBox "This computer is currently unreachable: " & strComputer, vbOKOnly, "Computer Status"
 '....your logic
 Else
'...your logic
 MsgBox "This computer is Online!", vbOKOnly, "Computer Status"
 End If
 End Sub 'TestPing
 
'

Comment: Determine if system is online
 Function SystemOnline(ByVal ComputerName As String)
Dim oShell, oExec As Variant
 Dim strText, strCmd As String
 
strText = ""
 strCmd = "ping -n 3 -w 1000 " & ComputerName
 Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set oExec = oShell.Exec(strCmd)
 
Do While Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
strText = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
 If InStr(strText, "Reply") > 0 Then
SystemOnline = True
 Exit Do
 End If
 Loop
 End Function

Comment: the only issue i can think of with the above code is it will be the router that responds to the ping not the server behind it

Comment: http://forums.devshed.com/visual-basic-programming-52/ping-from-vba-328706.html this is where i found above snippet of code